# RecyclerView under Swipe refresh layout is not showing in nested scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have view pager and recyclerview in my activity under scroll view.I am using recyclerview under swipe refresh layout.My problem is when I am using recyclerview without swipe refresh layout then it is showing in layout and if I wrap it under swipe refresh layout then it is not showing in layout.

This is my xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearHome"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="12dp"
android:paddingRight="12dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/homeOffers"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"/>

   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/refresh">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycle"/>

   </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Someone please let me know how can I achieve desired layout. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearHome"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progress2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:id="@+id/homeOffers"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                />

            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/refresh">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/recycle"/>

            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: It is working fine but how can I scroll view pager also.

Comment: How can I wrap entire layout in scroll view.